# Sharing x axis and y axis at the same time for images

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-gridspec

I have an image that I am displaying with imshow. Then I add all the rows and show maximum values. I do the same for the columns. On the display plot, I would like to make the x and y axis of the image coincide with the x axis of the addition of columns and the y axis with the adition of rows. However, despite setting `sharex` and `sharey` respectively, it just doesnt seem to work. I would I just seem to be able to do one at a time:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig=        plt.figure()
gs=         fig.add_gridspec(2,2, height_ratios=[1, 0.1], width_ratios=[1, 0.1], hspace=0, wspace=0)
ax1=        fig.add_subplot(gs[0,0])
ax2=        fig.add_subplot(gs[1,0], sharex=ax1)
ax3=        fig.add_subplot(gs[0,1], sharey=ax1)
frameNumber= 10
imgs=   []

for i in range(frameNumber):
    np.random.seed(i)
    randomImage= np.random.random((5,5))
    sumX=   np.sum(randomImage, axis=0)
    sumY=   np.sum(randomImage, axis=1)
    dataRange=  np.arange(len(sumX))
    randomDataSet=  np.random.random((10))
    randomMaximalX= argrelextrema(sumX, np.greater)
    randomMaximalY= argrelextrema(sumY, np.greater)

    img1=   ax1.imshow(randomImage, animated=True)
    img2=   ax2.plot(dataRange, sumX,animated=True)[0]
    img3=   ax3.plot(sumY,dataRange,animated=True)[0]
    img4=   ax2.vlines(x=randomMaximalX, ymin=0, ymax=5, animated=True, linestyles="dashed")
    img5=   ax3.hlines(y=randomMaximalY, xmin=0, xmax=5, animated=True, linestyles="dashed")
    imgs.append([img1, img2, img3, img4, img5])
ani=    animation.ArtistAnimation(fig, imgs, interval=1000, blit=False)
plt.show()
```

The current result is this:

[image]

And indeally I want something like this:

[image]

where H is the same value for both plots. Many thanks!

Comment: For some reason adding `figsize=(x,x)` to the `plt.figure()` function gets you what you want

Comment: Youre right! but it goes out when I resize the figure. I would love to add this graph to another figure that I am animating, so sadly this is not a viable solution for my use case :(

Comment: I think [this example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_hist.html) is relevant.  Note that the first method is like your existing, but sets a square figure, consistent with @Ftagliacarne’s comment.  The second method works on a non-square figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can approach this problem:

1. Use `Axes.pcolormesh` instead of `Axes.imshow`
2. OR update the aspect ratios of the adjacent plots.

#### ① Axes.pcolormesh

`Axes.pcolormesh` does not force the resultant image to be square (1:1 aspect ratio), so your cells will be rectangular but they'll appropriately fill the space provided.

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = default_rng(0)
image = rng.uniform(1, 10, size=(5, 5))

mosaic = [
    ['main',   'right'],
    ['bottom', '.'    ],
]

fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    mosaic,
    gridspec_kw={
        'height_ratios': [1, .1], 'width_ratios': [1, .1],
        'wspace': .05, 'hspace': .05,
    },
    sharex=True,
    sharey=True,
)

axd['main'].pcolormesh(image)

plt.show()
```

[image]

### ② Aspect Updating

If you want to stick with `Axes.imshow`, then you'll need to adjust the
aspect ratios of each plot manually. To get the correct ratios, you'll need
to calculate from the supplied `height_ratio` and `width_ratio` fed into the `GridSpec`

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rng = default_rng(0)
image = rng.uniform(1, 10, size=(5, 5))

mosaic = [
    ['main',   'right'],
    ['bottom', '.'    ],
]

fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    mosaic,
    sharex=True,
    sharey=True,
    gridspec_kw={
        'height_ratios': [1, .1], 'width_ratios': [1, .1],

        # change values to move adjacent plots closer to the main
        'wspace': .05, 'hspace': .05,
    },
)

axd['main'].imshow(image)
axd['main'].set_anchor('SE') # move main plot to bottom-right of bounding-box

# calculate the width and height scales
gs = axd['main'].get_gridspec() # you can also save these values from your `gridspec_kw`
width_scale = gs.get_width_ratios()[0]    / gs.get_width_ratios()[1]
height_scale = gs.get_height_ratios()[0]  / gs.get_height_ratios()[1]

# update the aspect ratios of the adjacent plots
#   set their anchors so they correctly align with the main plot
axd['right'].set_aspect(width_scale, anchor='SW')
axd['bottom'].set_aspect(1/height_scale, anchor='NE')

plt.show()
```

[image]